# signalR maintaining user connection ids

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, signalr

I am trying to maintain a connection id for the user ,i mean even he refreshes the page he gets the same connectionid

This is what i could do till now

the javascript part

```
// Start the connection            

            $.connection.hub.start(function () { chat.join(projectId, userId, userName); }).done(function () {
                alert("Connected!");
                var myClientId = $.connection.hub.id;
                setCookie("srConnectionid", myClientId, 1);

            });


            function setCookie(cName, value, exdays) {

              try{

                var exdate = new Date();
                exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);

                var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate);
                document.cookie = cName + "=" + c_value;

              }

             catch(err){

             alert(err.Description);             

             }
       }
```

and then i made a class that inherits IConnectionIdFactory like this

```
  public class MyConnectionFactory : IConnectionIdFactory
  {
    public string CreateConnectionId(IRequest request)
    {
        if (request.Cookies["srconnectionid"] != null)
        {
            return request.Cookies["srconnectionid"];
        }

        return Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }
  }
```

i registerd the above class in Application_start() as below

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {

        AspNetHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(IConnectionIdFactory), () => new MyConnectionFactory());     
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas(); 
        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```

My problem is everytime MyConnectionFactory class is called inside the CreateConnectionId
request.Cookies["srconnectionid"] is null everytime,so the user is assigned new connectionid everytime.I could find only one link that helped me to maintain connection ids.It is http://www.kevgriffin.com/maintaining-signalr-connectionids-across-page-instances

Can any one suggest how to fix my problem or is there any other approach to reuse the connection id for the same user...?

The Cookie value is set in the clientside.I have been trying this for 2 days.It would be great help

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you want to maintain the same connection ID? It seems to me that this could cause problems if for example the user opens another tab.

Comment: I am storing the connection id for the user after he logs in, in SQL server Db and then if i have to make that user join any room i get his connection id from db and Add the connection id to the group using AddToGroup().Basiclly i m doing it so that i can easily add him to any chatroom i could...

Comment: Why not use some other method like username or cookie information? You can even transfer this data in the connection state (edit: the hub state). It seems to me that abusing the connection ID to represent some other information (in your case the user) is not the right thing to do

Comment: can u please suggest the other way a bit more clear.Its not clear to me

Comment: how am i supposed to add people to chat room if i dont have their connectionids..?

Comment: You can call a method of the hub and pass it the relevant data. It is practically the same except that you are not abusing the connection ID but simply sending the data over the same connection that you have already established.

For example in your hub you may have a method Subscribe(int userID) in which you read the groups from the database based on the passed in userID and call AddToGroup for each group.

You can also use the Hub state to pass this data - https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/SignalR-JS-Client-Hubs (check the section about round tripping state)

Comment: Was this ever resolved?  I am having the same problem.

Comment: I am no longer working on signalR, but last time I knew I had stored the connection ids in a Http cookie on server side, I couldnt save the connection ids in client side.Later on I didnt save the connection ids.

Answer (score 1):

The expire date for the cookie should be UTC string (you are not doing this, so most probably the server is treating your cookie as expired). Change your code like this:

```
var cValue = escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie = cName + "=" + cValue;
```

Or you might just use [jQuery Cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) for setting the cookie.

UPDATE

Also the name of cookie is inconsitent in the code you have provided. You are setting the cookie with name 'userConnectionid' but trying to access by name 'srconnectionid'. Please check if you haven't made a spelling error there.

Comment: adding UTC doesnt help either

Comment: the cookie value is set but i could not access it in the class file its always null

Comment: I have updated with another thing I've noticed, please check. In case it will not work please check with FireBug if cookie is being send.

Comment: i m sorry for confusing.I have made the corrections.thanks for correctin,its correct in my code tho.Any other ideas..?

Comment: Please check with FireBug if the cookie is being send, and check all keys in Cookies container to see what you have there. From static code analysis it looks like it should work so we need to debug a little bit.

Comment: keys doesnt contain the cookie i have set,that is what i could not understand why the cookie value could not be passed on to the custom class file :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the cookie's path, especially if the page is sitting in a subdirectory.  I'm following a similar approach, and when the cookie path is set to root, then it all works.