# SignalR1.0.1 - Maintain connectionId

Tags: asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub

I'm using SignalR 1.0.1 and I want to maintain connection id even on page refresh.

Yes, I know, this is a common question of signalr so I got good answered post also but in all of them they mentioned **"IConnectionIdFactory"** interface which is missing in my app.

[1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518394/signalr-maintaining-user-connection-ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518394/signalr-maintaining-user-connection-ids)
[2) http://www.kevgriffin.com/maintaining-signalr-connectionids-across-page-instances/](http://www.kevgriffin.com/maintaining-signalr-connectionids-across-page-instances/)

Before this I was using SignalR alpha version and in that I have manage this issue using **"IConnectionIdPrefixGenerator"**. But in new version this interface is also missing.

Can anyone guide me How to fix this issue proper way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no longer any recommended pattern for setting or maintaining the connection id of a SignalR client in 1.0. I would suggest making single user groups in lieu of ConnectionIds.

[SignalR 1.0 beta connection factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14350158/signalr-1-0-beta-connection-factory/14350859#14350859)

If you don't need to use a custom string to address messages sent to a client and you can trust your clients, you can include metadata inside the query string of each SignalR request.

[How to parameterize a SignalR route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15486171/how-to-parameterize-a-signalr-route/15490737#15490737)